# different execution times for np.uint8 and np.int8

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have this piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import time
import numpy as np

for t in [np.uint8, np.int8]:
  a=np.empty([480, 640], t)
  v=[10, 245]
  for y in range(480):
    for x in range(640):
      a[y, x]=v[x&1]  # 50%=10, 50%=245
  t1=time.clock()
  a[a<32]=0
  a[a>224]=0
  t2=time.clock()
  print("%2.3f ms"%((t2-t1)*1000), a.dtype)
```

And I get this output:

```
3.162 ms uint8
0.329 ms int8
```

Why is this `a[a<32]=0` ten times faster, if it runs on a signed array?

Is there a way to speed it up on an unsigned array?

And yes...it's the same with more samples:

```
for t in [np.int8, np.uint8]:
  a=np.empty([480, 640], t)
  v=[10, 245]
  for y in range(480):
    for x in range(640):
      a[y, x]=v[x&1]  # 50%=10, 50%=235

  t1=time.process_time()
  for l in range(1000):
    b=1*a  # deep copy
    b[b<32]=0
    b[b>224]=0
  t2=time.process_time()
  print("%5.4f ms"%((t2-t1)*1000), a.dtype)
```

Result is this:

```
328.0701 ms int8
3081.5300 ms uint8
```

Comment: Testing in milliseconds is a bit uncertain. Did you run it only once? Did you try them the other way around?

Comment: I don't get significant time differences when using `np.int`, `np.int8` and `np.uint8`.  I'm working in `Ipython` with its `%%timeit`.

Comment: When I run your code I only get a 3x speed difference between `int8` and `uint8`.  And `uint8` runs in the same time as `int32` (and `uint32`).  That suggests there are only 2 calculation routes - a byte one used by `int8` and an integer (4byte) one.  `uint8` is probably cast to `int` for these purposes.

Comment: have you used an array filled with values, so that every value will be changed? Funny thing is, if I change v to [100, 145] (nothing to do for the b[b<32]=0 and b[b>224]=0), I get 1636.1527 ms for int8 and 114.9262 ms for uint8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure everyone knows where the time difference is coming from I broke the code down to each individual step:

**The whole code**

```
%%timeit 
tmp = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8, copy=True)
tmp[tmp < 30] = 0
tmp[tmp > 224] = 0
```

> 10 loops, best of 3: 21.6 ms per loop

```
%%timeit 
tmp = np.array(a, dtype=np.int8, copy=True)
tmp[tmp < 30] = 0
tmp[tmp > 224] = 0
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop

So yes the whole operation is faster, but let's look at the time spent in each of the **setting operations**:

```
%timeit tmp = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8, copy=True); tmp[tmp < 30] = 0
tmp = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8, copy=True)
tmp[tmp < 30] = 0
%timeit tmp2 = np.array(tmp, copy=True); tmp2[tmp2 > 224] = 0
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 19.3 ms per loop
>
> 100 loops, best of 3: 17.6 ms per loop

so each setting takes the same time while for `int8`:

> 100 loops, best of 3: 6.75 ms per loop
>
> 100 loops, best of 3: 4.36 ms per loop

Let's see what happens if we only **create a new view based on indexing**:

```
%timeit tmp = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8, copy=True); _ = tmp[tmp < 30]
tmp = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8, copy=True)
tmp[tmp < 30] = 0
%timeit tmp2 = np.array(tmp, copy=True); _ = tmp2[tmp2 > 224]
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop
>
> 100 loops, best of 3: 16.2 ms per loop

and for `int8`:

> 100 loops, best of 3: 7.64 ms per loop
>
> 100 loops, best of 3: 4.3 ms per loop

Still `int` is faster. so what about **creating the boolean mask**:

```
%timeit tmp = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8, copy=True); _ = tmp < 30
tmp = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8, copy=True)
tmp[tmp < 30] = 0
%timeit tmp2 = np.array(tmp, copy=True); _ = tmp2 > 224
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 4.25 ms per loop
>
> 100 loops, best of 3: 2.58 ms per loop

and for `int8`:

> 100 loops, best of 3: 4.26 ms per loop
>
> 100 loops, best of 3: 4.08 ms per loop

Long story short: While creating the boolean masks the dtype does not make a great difference but if you create a new view on the data with boolean masks it's much faster with `int`. But that's just an illusion because actually numpy sees that it accesses **all** elements in the first operation (since 235 get's translated to -21 in `int8`) and **no** element in the second operation. With `uint` the masks for **both** operations contain both True and False (mixed).

Summary: So numpy can and does optimize getting and setting all/no elements of an array.

In the comments you mentioned it's faster with `v=[10,100]` for `uint` but on my computer with the same setup as above it's both approximatly the same:

```
uint: 10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop
int:  10 loops, best of 3: 23.2 ms per loop
```

This is because now the first operation has a mixed boolean masks and numpy cannot optimize this as much as setting all/no element. But the second operation has a boolean mask with only `False` so numpy skips this for both uint and int.

Comment: My real script gets two images from a camera and then builds the difference to detect motion. And I still get 390.98 ms (when looping 1000 times) if I build the difference from an int8-array and 1383.07 ms, if I do the same on an uint8-array. See: http://dede67.bplaced.net/Arduino/ip_cam/ip_cam-WeitereErkenntnisse.html (in german language).

Comment: No the difference is not the ``dtype`` (I've checked with some example input in your modified script). Thedifference is that ``uint`` arrays have overflow. Suppose ``1-5`` with ``uint`` the result is 252 while for ``int`` it is -4. Your script will then mask this for int in the first operation while for uint it is only masked in the second operation. Depending on the dtype your program does different things. These different things are different in speed not because one is uint and one is int.

Comment: @dede - You can just check my conclusion by printing the ``np.sum(a<30)`` and ``np.sum(a>235)`` before you do the *replacing with zero* and you'll notice the difference due to overflow.

Comment: Correct - the `diff[diff>224]=0` is for handling the overflow. But even if I do both `diff[diff...]=0` unconditional (or always), I get the same execution times. Try it with the last script from my website: put the `diff[diff>224]=0` one level down. Then the script runs more code (the np.absolute()) for signed arrays - but it's doing it faster as for unsigned arrays. But try it with arrays filled with random [u]int8-values - or images.

Comment: Sorry but that's not really what you asked: You asked why in the specific case you mentioned in the question (and the alternative) the execution time is slower for ``uint`` than for ``int`` (or vise-versa) and that's explained in my answer (or maybe the answer is wrong). If you want to know why ``uint`` and ``int`` perform different (especially with difference images) that's beyond the scope of your original question and should not be discussed here but in a different question.

Comment: @dede- Just as example checkout https://github.com/MSeifert04/nddatadocs/blob/master/Sandbox.ipynb. uint is faster than int it's just that your example is ill-posed.

Comment: The script in my question is running the same (relevant) commands as the script on my website. And I built it as a demonstrator to have it short and tight. The only difference is the input-data. Here it were only two values, on my website it's an image with 256 arbitrarily spread values.

Comment: The problem with your camera is that the values are not arbitarily spread! And have you checked what I mentioned before? Printing the sums of your *masks* (``np.sum(a < 30)`` and ``np.sum(a > 235)``) and if yes what are these?

Comment: Yes I checked it. And you are right. There are no values above 235 in signed arrays - because it's signed and these values are below 0 here. But even if I delete the `diff[diff>224]=0`, the execution times are shorter for int then for uint. I'll rebuild my script with int8-arrays for grayscale images and convert it back to uint8, if I want to save them as a file.

Comment: I just have to ask: Did you at least tried my solution and found that you got the same results? Because I'm pretty certain it completly answers your posed question. I even showed you that ``uint``s are faster or as fast as ``int``s and what happens in you camera is mostly about statistics because that completly determines how many settings have to be done in your image. If you really find an example where ``int`` performs worse than ``uint`` post this example in your *next* question and not some hypothetical example where I showed you why the chosen example behaves worse for ``uint``!

Comment: I did some more tests and now agree with your conclusion. The difference comes from the sum of two things:
1) Setting ALL or NONE of the elements to zero runs much faster than setting some or many of the elements to zero.
2) The `b<32` also sets the elements below zero to zero when operating on `int8` - on `uint8` these elements would have values from 128 to 255.
And this was the problem in my demonstrator-script: for `int8` the `b[b<32]=0` sets ALL to zero and the `b[b>224]=0` sets NONE.
For `uint8` the `b[b<32]=0` sets 50% to zero and the `b[b>224]=0` the other 50%.